# How to run a method from other class properly?

Tags: objective-c, segue

I got the code in second (SKView) class:

```
 -(void)backToMenu
 {
     GamePlay1 *controller = [[GamePlay1 alloc]init];
     [controller end];
 }
```

In my first class i have this method that dismiss view controller:

```
 -(void)end
 {
      NSLog(@"I am here");

      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

It works just fine and i got the message "I am here".. But it won't trigger the dismiss line? Is maybe problem that i am creating new instance of class GamePlay1 instead calling the one that already exist? I am lost here don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you understand the actual problem

Try to create

//In appdegate .h

```
GamePlay1 *controller;
```

//In appdegate .m

```
controller = [[GamePlay1 alloc]init];
```

in `app delegate` file so that you will get access of controller object. Then it will trigger the dismiss

To access it use

```
AppDelegate  *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.controller end];
```